# About tag [polyglot-programming]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Currently, there are 9 questions under [polyglot-programming](/questions/tagged/polyglot-programming). IMHO, the use of this tag is not justified for most of theses questions. For instance, one question relates to both C# and F#, and has these two tags. No need for an additional tag.

So I'd like to propose the burnination of this tag.

Comment: There's only 9 and you have more than 2k, why not do it manually?

Comment: @Doorknob Always good to establish consensus on Meta before going on a tag burnination spree. Unless it's *really obviously* a horrible tag.

Comment: @Doorknob, I'd be glad to it manually, but I'd like to discuss it here first.

Comment: This seems sensible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I nuked the questions that should be nuked and removed the tag from the other questions.